# Concatenation of two regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

In a question, it is given that L is a finite language over the unary alphabet and L+ is not regular.
We know that L+ = LL*
Since L is finite, it must be regular because all finite languages are regular.
If L is regular L* is also regular.
Then how can be L+ not regular? It is the concatenation of two regular languages. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> it is given that L is a finite language over the unary alphabet and L+ is not regular.

That's impossible.  Since $L$ is finite, it is regular.  Since $L$ is regular, $L^+ = L L^*$ is regular.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties.

You're not wrong; you are right.

Comment: The more interesting question is what was intended, i.e., what modification to the statement would make it non-stupid.

Comment: Also, note that the unary alphabet doesn't give us anything new.